# New Windows 10 laptop, random keys stopped working in Windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have exhausted everything I can think of to fix this. This is a new Windows 10 installation on a new Dell G5 gaming laptop. Installed all of the programs needed which is basic stuff, MS Office, Eset for security, Adobe creative cloud, dropbox, slack, and some other routine off the shelf stuff. Initially everything worked fine, but at some point during installing everything, the numeric keypad stopped functioning as well as several arrow keys and about half the F keys. The numlock works but the 2 and 8 are the only keys that function on the numeric keypad. USB keyboard works fine, it's only the laptop keyboard with issues.

I have checked the basic stuff like mousekeys, done a sfc /scannow, booted in safe mode, tried a different user, etc., and still doesn't work. If I boot off a USB drive into freeDOS or a USB linux build, all of the keys work fine, so it's something windows / software related. But, safemode doesn't fix anything, so having trouble identifying the issue.

Looking for any suggestion on even how to troubleshoot this further. Should I do a repair upgrade installation or is there some other route that someone would recommend to figure this out?

Comment: How about removing the keyboard in device manager, and then doing a hardware changes scan and see if it's re-detected?

Comment: Call Dell Support as they should be able to test for you and give you the next steps. Warranty service.

Comment: @spikey_richie, tried removing it and it forces a reboot and auto-reinstalls when I reboot so don't get the typical check for new hardware fix. But, same result when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Sounds to me like a defect (like e.g. broken or loose ribbon, or a cold solder joint[s]) causing it.**

If it would be anything software related the USB one would also not work as they are basically controlled by the same software within the OS.

Or if push comes to shove a reboot would fix it. Since it sounds like a doesn't and it is more than one key, I would eliminate software or random dirt as cause.

That sometimes happens even on new machines. A bad solder joint or a component not up to snuff and it suddenly fails. Or a ribbon connector isn't properly closed and & or becomes loose in shipping.

As one of the comments already said contact Dell Support for repair/replacement under warranty (tho, they will probably do some tests first to make sure it is a warranty case)

Good luck, I hope it will be soon back to 100%.

Comment: Would it make a difference that in hardware properties the keyboard is listed as PS2? That's why I was ruling out a USB issue. It's not one key though, it's at least 20 keys, most of them in the numeric pad though.